# How to create image curved using css or jquery (See picture)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, effect

Do you know how to take an effect like this: [Image](http://oi39.tinypic.com/2hs245k.jpg)
[image]

when hovering on the picture?

I keep searching css and jquery but still not reach what i need.

Please give me a solution to do this.

Thank you so much!

(Sorry about my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS border-radius property and apply it on hover, e.g. something like:

```
#img:hover {
    border-top-right-radius:50% 10%;
    border-top-left-radius:50% 10%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50% 10%;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50% 10%
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r3KzP/1/

Comment: Thanks so much. It maybe the best solution till now for me. Thanks for amazing tip.

Comment: You're welcome. If you need in addition to stretch your image (like in your example) just add `width` and `height` property to the above CSS for additional effect.

Comment: Yeah, i get it. Thanks again :D

Comment: thats not bend, but like crop