# Bend an image based on a slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-processing

Referring to this post: [How to create image curved using css or jquery (See picture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871728/how-to-create-image-curved-using-css-or-jquery-see-picture) and this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVRLv/

How can I enable the picture to stretch too? Not only a box-radius.

I want to be able to make a curved form of an image controllable with a value of how much it is bended.

I've already figured out how to change the width and size of my image:

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Trust Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>


<img src="http://www.discoposse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/test-all-the-things.jpg" id="image"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  value: 0,
  step: .001,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#image").width(ui.value * 100);
        $("#image").height(ui.value * 50);
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

Thank you in advance!

Stijn

Comment: I'll guess that you probably can't "bend" and image on the clientside, even if you could probably load it into a canvas and modify the canvas etc.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the stretching effect you created with a border radius may give the desired effect.

You can edit the styling of an image with jQuery's `.css()` method.

In this case you can use that within the slider's `slide` event to dynamically alter the border of your image to make it appear bent.

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  value: 0,
  step: .001,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#image").width(ui.value * 100);
        $("#image").height(200);
        $('#image').css('border-top-left-radius', '50% 15px')
        $('#image').css('border-top-right-radius', '50% 15px')
        $('#image').css('border-bottom-left-radius', '50% 15px')
        $('#image').css('border-bottom-right-radius', '50% 15px')
  }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeuogbty/) with the above code. Of course the values can be altered to customize the effect.